# How do I have Intersecting Faces?

Tags: faces, 3d-printing

I have this problem quite a bit and I can not figure out why. I have looked up many posts in several forums but no one seems to have had this problem (that I can find). This appears to be a bug in the intersecting faces part of the 3d printing plugin. It happens in both 2.8 and 2.79b.

In this model I have 2 intersecting faces, yet they are not as you can see. Other times I have faces intersecting at a vertex, but again are not intersecting as they are just sharing that vertex. If I triangulate this model, it will have several intersecting faces at shared vertices, some of which do not exist now. I have also had models where I change something and the intersecting faces will disappear, even when I haven't touched them.

[image]

Comment: I have had the same thing happen to me many times as well. Sometimes deleting the face and then adding the exact same face back again will 'fix' it. So these days I generally ignore that part of the plugin.